# angular unit test $attrs in link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

I have set up some tests with for directives that have controllers.  It was not too difficult to set up

```
        var html = angular.element("<div explore></div>");
        $rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = $compile(html)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest(element);

        controller = element.scope();
```

However, I am a little confused about the link function.  Example is not code from app, but similar.

```
var exploreLink = function($scope, $el, $attr) {
   $scope.gallery = [];

    $scope.secondarytitle = $attrs.title;
}



return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: ExploreLinks,
    templateUrl: 'LinkHtml'
    controller: LinkController
};
```

If I mock out  **$rootScope**   is there a way to access $attr?   I did not see

```
  $attr
```

on $rootScope.

It seems that I would still call $digest since it is part of a directive.  I am assuming its necessary to compile a directive similar to the steps listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link` is a terrible place for unit testing, its contents should be left to E2E tests, or the whole directive should be treated as black box and its results have to be matched against scope object.

It is ok if it contains DOM-related logic that should be tested with Protractor. And it is not ok if linking function contains something that should belong to controller, according to the formula 'controller binds the things to scope, link glues the things together'.

Each registered directive is available as Angular service with `*Directive` name, and parts of it can be tested or mocked. The fact that `link` function is buried inside `compile` function in DDO objects doesn't make the task easier or cleaner.

Testing linking functions may be as creepy as that

```
  inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, exploreDirective) {
    ...
    var linkFn;
    var _compileFn = exploreDirective[0].compile;
    var _attrs;

    spyOn(exploreDirective[0], 'compile').and.callFake(function () {
      var _linkFn = _compileFn.apply(exploreDirective[0], arguments);

      var linkFn = jasmine.createSpy('linkFn');
      linkFn.and.callFake(function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn) {
        // now attrs can be mocked or matched
        _attrs = attrs;
        return _linkFn(function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn);
      }

      return linkFn;
    });

    $compile('<explore attr="...">')(scope);
    expect(linkFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(_attrs.attr).toBe('...');
```

Always use `$attrs` local dependency in directive controller in favour of `attrs` param in `link` for testing. Assigning attrs to `this` or `$scope` in controller is the right thing to do here.

And by the way, internal Angular logic shouldn't be mocked or tested. It is safe to assume that `$compile('<explore attr="...">')(scope)` will result in `$attrs.attr === '...'`.

Comment: I do not quite follow the element[0].compile.  At that point it is undefined correct?

Comment: @stevek Do you mean `exploreDirective[0].compile`? It is defined if `explore` directive was defined. If there was no `compile` function defined on the directive,  `exploreDirective[0].compile` contains a dummy function that returns `link` function.